# Round bottom line of an image view

Tags: ios, swift, image, layer

I want only the bottom border of my `imageView` to be rounded. How do I do that programmatically?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can do some workaround with BEZIER Paths

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing UIButton to have rounded corners on one side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43986812/editing-uibutton-to-have-rounded-corners-on-one-side)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round Top Corners of a UIButton in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163850/round-top-corners-of-a-uibutton-in-swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by sub-classing UIImageView:

```
import UIKit
class CustomImageView: UIImageView {

override public func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.roundUpCorners([.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 30)
}
}
extension UIView {
func roundUpCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
}
}
```

The result will be something like this:[image]